# How to tell which client did the user send a Slack with? (e.g. mobile, desktop, web)

Tags: slack, slack-api, chatbot

Is there a way to know what client was used to send a particular message in Slack? e.g. Mobile App Mac OS, Desktop App Windows, Web Client Chrome

For example, if an user sent a message to my bot via DM, I'll like to know which client the user is currently on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that information is not available in the Slack API.